# Android Studio: Genymotion Issues

Tags: genymotion

When opening Android Studio i've encountered the issue of being unable to run a genymotion device via the two ways applicable [The genymotion icon and via the run configuration]?

Update：

**Software Versions**:

> Genymotion version:2.4.0   
>  Android Studio version:1.0   
>  Operating
>   System：win 7

**Android Studio displays**:

> 22:17:38 Genymotion  Listing virtual
>   machines and found Genymotion virtual device...
>
> 22:19:59 Genymotion: Launch process:
>   F:\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list vms  22:19:59 Genymotion 
>   [SUCCESS] Process: F:\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list vms
>
> 22:19:59 Genymotion Listing virtual machines and found Genymotion
>   virtual device...

PS:I have two devices in Genymotion already downloaded, they can work in genymotion but can not display in Android Studio.

Comment: can you provide us with any errors that are being displayed?

Comment: I'm sorry I can not provide any error, because he did not prompt any error, it can be used before, today suddenly can not be used.Is there anyone encountered this situation?

Comment: have you changed the Android Studio SDKs to be linked with Genymotion's SDKs?

Comment: I think the problem is in ADB, I just saw my process there are three ADB running，I try to kill them but android studio still can not find devices.

Comment: hmm very strange, try reinstalling genymotion and try again and let me know how you get on. if the problem persists, i'll discuss this with you in a chatroom.

Comment: can you give me your chat software number or anything else?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77000/genymotion-with-android-studio-issues

Comment: android studio prompt me  Listing virtual machines and found Genymotion virtual device...but it do not show the virtual machines already exists

Comment: take this onto the chatroom buddy. we can't hold a discussion within the comments.

Comment: My reputation is not enoug to talk in the chatroom..sorry..

Comment: no problem bud, i'll see what i can do.

Comment: please add any information about the hardware you are using to the question, such as what operating system and which version? anything android studio is telling you (displaying certain virtual devices etc or not displaying certain virtual devices) i think i may have found a solution depending on the context of your issue. when you update the question, let me know.

Comment: the genymotion's main purpose is to run a virtual machine outside of Android Studio. open the genymotion program, open the device you wish to use. go into Android Studio, right click > debug > select the genymotion device you wish to debug on. Then move over to the genymotion virtual device which is open outside of Android Studio, give it a chance to load and it should be there for you.

Comment: oh,you solve my problem,Wilson.

Comment: thats great bud! i'll post is as an answer to close the question for future readers

Comment: it still can not find the Genymotion device when I click the Genymotion button,but it can find when I run the or debug.I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expansion from comments for future readers:

Genymotion's main purpose is to run a [Virtual Machine](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide)  outside of Android Studio. Take these steps:

1. Open Genymotion
2. Open the device you wish to use [if it's your first time, download an appriopriate device and then open it]
3. Go into Android Studio
4. Right click on the desired project
5. Click Debug
6. Select the Genymotion device you have open
7. Go back to Genymotion and wait it shouldn't take long to load.

Note: Ensure that when you click the Genymotion icon inside Android Studio and it shows up a 'preferences' dialog, you should place the file path to the Genymotion program inside the area provided. Click finish. When you click the icon again it should show you the devices that are available. see [Android Studio + Genymotion](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2013/11/22/android-studio-plus-genymotion-emulator/) tutorial.